# Find missing entries in one file

Tags: regex

I've got two files:

1st: **Entries.txt**

```
confirmation.resend
send
confirmation.showResendForm
login.header
login.loginBtn
```

2nd: **Used_Entries.txt**

```
confirmation.showResendForm = some value
login.header = some other value
```

I want to find all entries from the first file (**Entries.txt**) that have not been asigned a value in the 2nd file (**Used_Entries.txt**)

In this example I'd like the following **result**:

```
confirmation.resend
send
login.loginBtn
```

In the result `confirmation.showResendForm` and `login.header` do not show up because these exist in the **Used_Entries.txt**

How do I do this? I've been playing around with regular expressions but haven't been able to solve it. A bash script or sth would be much appreciated!

Comment: First of all... What flavour is your regex engine? "_I've been playing around with regular expressions but haven't been able to solve it._" Show your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex. But get your code mood ready, because you can't match both files with regex at once, and we **do** want to match both contents with regex at once. Well, that means you must have at least some understanding of your language, I would like you to concatenate the contents from the two files with at least a new line in between.

This regex solution expects your string to be matched to be in this format:

```
text (no equals sign)
text
text
...
key (no equals sign) ␣ (optional whitespace) = (literal equal) whatever (our regex will skip this part.)
key=whatever
key=whatever
```

---

Do I have your attention? Yes? Please see the following regex (using techniques accessible to most regex engines):

```
/(^[^=\n]+$)(?!(?s).*^\1\s*=)/m
```

Inspired from [a recent answer I saw from zx81](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947518/3622940), you can **switch to `(?s)` flag in the middle** to switch to DOTALL mode suddenly, allowing you to start multiline matching with `.` in the middle of a RegExp. Using this technique and the set syntax above, here's what the regex does, as **an explanation**:

- `(^[^=\n]+$)` Goes through all the `text (no equals sign)` elements. Enforces no equals signs or newlines in the capture. This means our regex hits every `text` element as a line, and tries to match it appropriately.
- `(?!` Opens a negative lookahead group. Asserts that this match will **not** locate the following:
- `(?s).*` Any number of characters or new lines - As this is a greedy match, will throw our matcher pointer to the very end of the string, skipping to the last parts of the document to backtrack and scoop up quickly.
- `^\1\s*=` The captured key, followed by an equals sign after some optional whitespaces, in its own line.
- `)` Ends our group.

[View a Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG2lJ8/3)!

[A regex demo with more test cases](http://regex101.com/r/nG2lJ8/4)

---

I'm stupid. I could had just put this:

```
/(^[^=\n]+$)(?!.*^\1\s*=)/sm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    e=open("Entries.txt",'r')
    m=e.readlines()
    u=open("Used_Entries.txt",'r')
    s=u.read()
    y=re.sub(r"= .*","",s)
    for i in m:
        if i.strip() in [k.strip() for k in y.split("\n")] :
            pass
    else:
        print i.strip()
```

Comment: Thx for your help! One (newbie) question though: How do i run this?

Comment: In python u can run this straightaway .Please maintain the indentation.

Comment: This gives me the following output: ['confirmation.resend\n', 'send\n', 'confirmation.showResendForm\n', 'login.header\n', 'login.loginBtn']. This does not seem to be correct. Have you considered that in the Used_Entries.txt the entries are assigned a value (for example " = some value")?

Comment: The output looks nicer now (every entry is printed on a new line without '\n' etc) but it still prints every entry from Entry.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I've been going at this a little bit to complex and just solved it with a small script in scala:

```
import scala.io.Source

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val entries = (for(line <- Source.fromFile("Entries.txt").getLines()) yield {
      line
    }).toList

    val usedEntries = (for(line <- Source.fromFile("Used_Entries.txt").getLines()) yield {
      line.dropRight(line.length - line.indexOf(' '))
    }).toList

    println(entries)
    println(usedEntries)

    val missingEntries = (for {
      entry <- entries
      if !usedEntries.exists(_ == entry)
    } yield {
      entry
    }).toList

    println(missingEntries)

    println("Missing Entries: ")
    println()
    for {
      missingEntry <- missingEntries
    } yield {
      println(missingEntry)
    }

  }
}
```